# Displaying upcoming Facebook events on site, works for one page and not the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, widget

I found a generator that allows you to embed some HTML which displays upcoming Facebook events from a Facebook page.

Here's the code that I used, based it off of a temporary Facebook page I created, this code works fine:

```
<iframe src="http://www.bandrx.com/facebook/events.php?theme=zuck&page=samtestmaze/events&bgcolor=ffffff&textcolor=000000&linkcolor=555555&max=5" width="320" height="520" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

But when I do it with this Facebook page (Facebook.com/themazerio/events) it doesn't seem to show upcoming events. Here's the code (not working):

```
<iframe src="http://www.bandrx.com/facebook/events.php?theme=zuck&page=themazerio/events&bgcolor=ffffff&textcolor=000000&linkcolor=555555&max=5" width="320" height="520" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

I know it's picking up the right page because it shows how many people like that page in the like counter, but it's not showing upcoming events.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Are the events public for this "themazerio" page? I can't think of any other reason why it wouldn't work besides Facebook privacy settings for the page

Comment: @Aaron that seems to be the case. TheMazeRio page is not public and only people logged in can view it.

Comment: That might be the case, thanks for suggesting that. I'll contact the owner and ask him to change it to public. Thanks!

Comment: How does one make a Facebook 'page' public? When you manage a 'page' there is no privacy settings like on a profile, so the controls must be elsewhere but I'm struggling to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654390/displaying-upcoming-facebook-events-on-site-works-for-one-page-and-not-the-othe#comment58989480_35654390) in the comments, the problem is not code-related, it is simply not working because the facebook page "[TheMazeRio](https://www.facebook.com/TheMazeRio)" is not visible to users not logged in to facebook.

Here are the main factors that prevent "guests" from viewing a facebook page:

**1 – Country Restriction:**

> In case you have applied this, Your page will not be visible to fans
>   of other countries. Country restricted pages can only be visited by
>   logging in. So make sure there should be no country restrictions.

**2 – Age restriction:**

> Age restriction is also a constraint that makes your Facebook page
>   visible for selective users/fans or for a particular age group. Make
>   sure there is no age restriction on your page otherwise it will not be
>   visible to certain users without logging in to Facebook.

**3 – Profanity Blacklist:**

> If you have selected an option other than “none” your page will not be
>   public. Users must be logged in to view your page.

**4 – Moderation Blacklist:**

> If there is anything written in that box, your  page will not be
>   public. Someone must be logged in, in order to view your
>   page. Restrictions are a good tool to make your Facebook page more
>   compliant with your business or product.

Source: [How to make your Facebook page publicly visible](http://facebook-buy-fans.com/make-facebook-page-publicly-visible/)

[image: facebook visibility restrictions]

P.S. You can always test the public visibility of a facebook page easily by opening the page link in a private/incognito browser window, or logging out of your facebook.